# Como solucionar error al instalar pandas para python en windows?

Tags: python, pandas, windows

Como solucionar error que aparece al intentar instalar pandas a través de la terminal con comando: pip install pandas. Se generan multiples errores que no han dejado avanzar. Esto también ocurre al intentar instalar el paquete Numpy.

Como solucionar error que aparece al intentar instalar pandas a través de la terminal con comando: pip install pandas. Se generan multiples errores que no han dejado avanzar. Esto también ocurre al intentar instalar el paquete Numpy.

Como solucionar error que aparece al intentar instalar pandas a través de la terminal con comando: pip install pandas. Se generan multiples errores que no han dejado avanzar. Esto también ocurre al intentar instalar el paquete Numpy.

error:

```
C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\Downloads>pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.1.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g9gx3s69\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (696 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.17.3
    Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CONTRALORIA-02\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hegxedix\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CONTRALORIA-02\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hegxedix\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-y1kecbkf'
         cwd: C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\
    Complete output (319 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    "svnversion" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
    programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\setup.py", line 443, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 142, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 286, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 369, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info
        st = config_cmd.try_link('int main(void) { return 0;}')
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 241, in try_link
        self._check_compiler()
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 42, in _check_compiler
        old_config._check_compiler(self)
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 97, in _check_compiler
        self.compiler = new_compiler(compiler=self.compiler,
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 765, in new_compiler
        compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
      File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 68, in __init__
        distutils.cygwinccompiler.CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose,
      File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 124, in __init__
        if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
    Running setup.py clean for numpy
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CONTRALORIA-02\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hegxedix\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CONTRALORIA-02\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hegxedix\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
         cwd: C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy
    Complete output (10 lines):
    R

      flame_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\contraloria-02\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 97, in _check_compiler
          self.compiler = new_compiler(compiler=self.compiler,
        File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 765, in new_compiler
          compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
        File "C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hegxedix\numpy\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 68, in __init__
          distutils.cygwinccompiler.CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose,
        File "c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 124, in __init__
          if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
      TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CONTRALORIA-02\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hegxedix\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CONTRALORIA-02\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hegxedix\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z10ykyjz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g9gx3s69\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g9gx3s69\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\CONTRALORIA-02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-g9gx3s69\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor copia el código en **formato texto** y pon toda la traza de error por completo. Esto nos dará más ideas de lo que está pasando. Las imagenes de código solo entorpecen a las personas que quieren ayudarte. Por ahora parece que puede ser un error de la versión de Python, la versión de PiP o que te faltan paquetes de C++ para estas librerías.

Comment: Dejo texto del error, agradezco ayuda.

Comment: Para windows creo que lo más simple es que instales anaconda. Es una distribución para Windows que te instala fácilmente (directamente desde un instalador que descargas de su web) python y montones de bibliotecas típicas para computación científica (pandas, numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc..) ya precompiladas y configuradas para tu plataforma

Comment: Gracias por la info añadida, abajo respondo a tu pregunta, espero que te sirva.  El comentario de @abulafia es muy acertado, ya que si no sabes muy bien que sucede, Anaconda te resuelve muuuuuuchos problemas automáticamente.

Answer (score 2):

Tu error es que tienes la versión de Python 3.9. Esta versión ha salido hace escasos días (el 5 de octubre) y la librería Numpy al igual que muchas otras, todavía no han actualizado sus paquetes a esta versión.

**¿Cómo sé esto?**

En los multiples errores que hay aparece varios de este tipo:

```
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
```

Esto quiere decir que no está encontrando una versión compatible para `Numpy`, aun así, va a intentar instalarlo.

Sé que tienes la versión 3.9 porque siempre que el programa va a buscar carpetas o librerías va a este path:

```
c:\users\contraloria-02\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
```

Por último al ir a **PypI** ([aquí](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/)) de `Numpy` puedes ver como **la última versión soportada es Python 3.8** y que la última versión estable se publicó el **10 de septiembre** Numpy 1.19.2.

### Solución

Una vez explicado todo esto, obviamente la solución es instalar cualquier versión de Python permitida por `Numpy`, Python 3.7 o Python 3.8 por ejemplo.

Mi recomendación es que **cada vez que salga una versión de Python nueva, tardes unos meses en instalarla o incluso un año** (Tensorflow por ejemplo no ha resuelto aun errores con Python 3.8). Esto se debe a que el ecosistema de Python y las librerías, no es una empresa, si no un software de contribución libre, por lo tanto cada uno va *"por su cuenta"* y hasta las librerías más usadas, y con más contribuyentes tardan un tiempo en actualizarse.