# ¿Por qué Anaconda no actualiza a la última version de Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Tengo instalada la última versión de Python, que es la 3.9, que utilizo en VSCode y Sublime Text 3.

Y por otro lado tengo instalado Anaconda, ya que uso el IDE Spyder para utilizar paquetes que ya vienen instalados ahí. Como salió una nueva versión de Python, pensé que Anaconda iba a actualizarse solo, pero no lo hizo. Y cuando lo actualizo manualmente, no toma que hay una nueva versión de Python, y sigue usando la anterior.

¿Hay alguna manera de que se pueda instalar la última versión de Python dentro de Anaconda?

Gracias, y saludos!

Comment: Normalmente, las dependencias impiden que anaconda se actualize a la últimísima versión de python. Tampoco es recomendable, ya que podrías quedarte en un estado inestable si se produjera algún error o fallara alguna cosa. Lo recomendable es dejar a anaconda que decida cuál es su versión estable y usar un nuevo entorno para trabajar. En vscode podrás elegir el entorno de trabajo e, incluso, podrá instalar en él los módulos que necesite.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que verificar tu forma de actualizar

A partir del 15 de octubre de 2020, las dependencias básicas parecen haberse solucionado y el siguiente comando ahora funciona:

```
conda create -c conda-forge python=3.9 -n py39-demo
```

Comment: Agregar que aquí realmente no estás actualizando. Lo que se hace es crear un entorno nuevo de Python, con Python 3.9, **lo cual es lo correcto** ya que actualizar podría hacer que tu anterior entorno dejase de funcionar. Por último una advertencia de actualizar a las versiones más recientes al poco tiempo de salir [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399548/como-solucionar-error-al-instalar-pandas-para-python-en-windows/399700#399700). Buena respuesta!

Comment: Gracias! Saludos