# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me funcione la importación del pandas as pd?

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

En mi proyecto he intentado importar pandas, previa instalación del último paquete en mi iMac.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Queriendo hacer un DataFrame :

```
dt= pd.DateFrame({'Nombre':equipos, 'Puntos':puntos}, index=list(range(1,21)))

print(dt)
```

Al intentar verlo por consola me sale esté error:

```
danielgil@iMac-de-Daniel Curso_Python % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 "/Users/danielgil/Desktop/Curso_Python/Crawlers/Proyecto crawler/WEB SCRAPING.PY"
Python(2453,0x114627dc0) malloc: can't allocate region
:*** **mach_vm_map(size=18446744071931523072, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
Python(2453,0x114627dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
init_dgelsd failed init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/danielgil/Desktop/Curso_Python/Crawlers/Proyecto crawler/WEB SCRAPING.PY", line 8, in <module>
    import pandas as pd 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

Comment: Parece que hay algo mal con tu instalación de pandas. ¿Cómo lo instalaste? Te recomiendo que descargues [anaconda python](https://www.anaconda.com/) que es una distrribución de python junto con montones de bibliotecas típicas para data science, compilado para Windows y configurado para que funcione correctamente. Veo por otro lado que estás usando python 3.9 que casi acaba de salir. Igual por ahi viene también algún problema.

Comment: Por cierto... ese pedazo de malloc de 18446744071931523072 bytes??? Son más de 16 millones de petabytes! (en realidad es casi casi 2**64 así que parece algún bug relacionado con un tamaño negativo)

Comment: La verdad que la instalación que seguí ( dados mis pocos conocimientos) fue el típico: pip3 Install pandas. Por otro lado, tengo que estudiar lo que me comentas de la instalación de anaconda ( he oido hablar de ellas, pero no sé muy bien como instalarla).

Comment: Pues lo dicho, y si estás empezando más a mi favor, anaconda es una distribución que te puede ahorrar muchos quebraderos de cabeza

Comment: Voy a mirar algún tutoría para la instalación de anconda. Mi duda es si servirá también para Mac...

Comment: Es tan fácil como descargar el instalador y ejecutarlo. Tardará lo suyo porque se baja muchas cosas. Al final te deja una carpeta "Anaconda" donde trae su propio python y todo lo demás. No necesitas desinstalar lo que tienes ahora, puede convivir. Lanza un "Anaconda shell" (a través del menú de Windows) para desde él poder ejecutar tus scripts de modo que usen el python de anaconda en vez del otro

Comment: Me has dejado resulta varias dudas. Tengo que mirarlo para el sistema operativo de OS Catalina que es con el que trabajo. Pero por lo que me dejas explicado es muy intuitivo. Voy a ello, espero poder arreglar al menos está parte... Muchas gracias

Comment: Además de los buenos consejos de Abufalia, te remito [a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399548/como-solucionar-error-al-instalar-pandas-para-python-en-windows/399700#399700). El error viene de Numpy, otra librería que es muy usada por Pandas, Numpy está teniendo multiples errores con la última versión de python 3.9. Te recomiendo instalar la versión Python 3.8