# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "pandas" en Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, vscode, pip, anaconda

Estoy aprendiendo a usar python (Primer lenguaje que aprendo)Tengo un problema que me tiene loco hace 16 horas.
Al instalar pandas mediante pip.

```
pip install pandas
```

Se instala todo perfecto, acá utilizando

```
pip show pandas
```

[image: cmd show pandas]

Y al probarlo en visual studio sucede esto:

[image: visual studio code pandas]

Probé en el cmd primero ingresando Python:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego probé usando Python3:
[image: Python3 cmd]

Ya instale todo devuelta , probé con anaconda e instale y desinstale todo 30 veces
También cambié el PAHT en la variable del sistema como se ve aca:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Por lo que veo con python3, si te agarra, cuál es el problema?

Comment: Tienes la versión de Python 3.9 que ha salido recientemente, y está dando ciertos problemas a algunas librerías com prueba a instalar Python 3.8. Tienes una explicación de por qué sucede [en esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399548/como-solucionar-error-al-instalar-pandas-para-python-en-windows/399700#399700)

Comment: En VSCode tienes que especificar qué intérprete Python quieres que use. Por defecto se ve que te usa python3.9 en vez de python3.8 que es la versión para la que habías instalado Pandas. Pulsa Ctrl+Mayus+P y escribe "Python select interpreter"

Answer (score 1):

Como bien mencionaron en otro comentario, estás trabajando con el último release de python (3.9.0), lo tenés indicado en la interfaz de las variables de entorno que subiste como imagen , siempre se recomienda no trabajar con las últimas versiones/releases por temas de compatibilidad, como recomendación desinstala todas las versiones de python e instalate la penúltima versión. Un Saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo el mismo problema, al parecer el comando `pip` instala el modulo para la versión 2.x de `python`, he tratado de instalarlo manual mente para la versión 3 sin éxito, si no necesitas usar la versión 3 de `python` trata de ejecutar tus scripts con la versión 2.

Si necesitas utilizar módulos para la versión 3 te recomiendo uses el `ide pycharm`, cuando importes el modulo de pandas te lo marcara como error y te sugerirá instalarlo solo debes darle clic a instalar y el hará todo el proceso.